# How can i access variable in Pyspark just like in Scala by using s & $

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a code below which is used to copy the data from HIVE table to HDFS in append mode as Parquet file.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import current_date, date_format, date_sub
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import datetime
q = """select label_yyyy_mm_dd
        ,label_yyyy_mm
        ,q_media_name
        ,a_accepted
        ,a_end_ts
        ,a_media_name
        ,a_resource_name
        ,a_start_ts
        ,k_callpurpose
        ,k_srf
        ,q_entry_ordinal
        ,q_interaction_id
        ,q_interaction_type
        ,q_ixn_resource_id
        ,q_resource_name
        ,a_consult_rcv_warm_engage_time
        ,a_consult_rcv_warm_hold_time
        ,a_consult_rcv_warm_wrap_time
        ,a_customer_handle_count
        ,a_customer_talk_duration
        ,a_interaction_resource_id
        ,a_interaction_id
        ,a_wrap_time
        a_technical_result
        ,k_ixn_type
        ,k_ixn_type_source
        ,k_transfer_count
        ,k_language
        ,k_agentauth
        ,k_auth,k_rg
        ,k_channel
        ,k_gms_result
        ,k_connid
        ,k_rbcprimaryid
        ,k_agent_id
        ,a_interaction_resource_ordinal 
    from prod_T0V0_cct0.cct0_gim_measures_gold A 
    inner join prod_T0V0_cct0.yle0_gim_date_time B on A.a_start_date_time_key = B.date_time_key 
    where label_yyyy_mm_dd = date_format(date_sub(current_date(), 1), 'y-MM-dd')
  """
date = (datetime.date.today()-datetime.timedelta(days=1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
spark.sql(q).write.mode('append').parquet('hdfs:/prod/11323/app/H9A0/data/T0V0/DIG/info_gold_chat.parquet/label_yyyy_mm_dd=$date')
```

The parquet file needs to be moved by creating folder as per the value of the variable "date". However this is throwing syntax error as i can understand that the above path has 's' and '$' which is for Scala and not Pyspark. I tried removing both of them and it works however the files goes and sits into a folder name "date" which i think it treats as a constant and not variable value.

> Can someone help me on how to write the parquet files into folder
>   having the name as Day-1 (%y-%m-%d) format ?

Comment: Show the exact error message you get. [Edit] this question and format the code and messages properly so this is actually readable.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with the last line, I have tested the data in Pyspark shell, its giving the correct result. Use proper String formatting in last line in PySpark as below:

```
date = (datetime.date.today()-datetime.timedelta(days=1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

date # Testing the date value in PySpark Shell.
'2018-09-24'

spark.sql(q).write.mode('append').parquet('hdfs:/prod/11323/app/H9A0/data/T0V0/DIG/info_gold_chat.parquet/label_yyyy_mm_dd=%s' %date')
```

Comment: File "<ipython-input-6-48130be30680>", line 45
    spark.sql(q).write.mode('append').parquet('hdfs:/prod/11323/app/H9A0/data/T0V0/DIG/info_gold_chat.parquet/label_yyyy_mm_dd=%s' %date')
                                                                                                                                         ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Comment: spark.sql(q).write.mode('append').parquet('hdfs:/prod/11323/app/H9A0/data/T0V0/DIG/info_gold_chat.parquet/label_yyyy_mm_dd=%s' %date)

Comment: There is extra quotation mark, removed it.. please try again now. I have tested in my local: test = 'hdfs:/prod/11323/app/H9A0/data/T0V0/DIG/info_gold_chat.parquet/label_yyyy_mm_dd=%s' %date

Comment: >>> test
'hdfs:/prod/11323/app/H9A0/data/T0V0/DIG/info_gold_chat.parquet/label_yyyy_mm_dd=2018-09-24'

Comment: Yes, it worked out...i removed the ' from after date. Thanks a lot Sir!